# Internal Transactions - How to find out the address of the contract that is calling?

Tags: solidity, cpp-ethereum, internal-transactions

i have been Googling for this answer, but i haven`t succeeded.

The  scenario is the following:  I have two contracts interacting with each other, and I want to make sure that they only respond to each other. Meaning that if anyone else, or other contracts try to call their functions, the transaction must be reverted.

In order to achieve that, tried adding something like "require(msg.sender==addrContractA)" to the functions that i want to restrict but it does not workout.

Please look at the example below.

```
contract B {
     // Some code here...
     address addrA;
     receive() public payable {
        require(msg.sender ==addrA, "Error- Sender not allowed");
        // Some more code here...
     }


    function setAddressA(address _addrA) public onlyOwner{ addrA = _addrA;}
}

contract A{
     // Some code here...
   address b;
   ...

   constructor(address payable _b) public { 
       b =_b; 
   }
   receive() payable external{
      ...
      b.transfer(msg.value);
   }
}
```

The system is expected to behave like this:

- A person sends eth to contract A, contract A passes the value along to contract B.
- When the value hits contract B, it must verify if the sender is contract A. Any value that did not pass through contract A must be refused by reverting the transaction.

Problem here is that I do not know what variable I could inspect to get the address of the "internal sender". Something like msg.sender, but the variable "msg.sender"  always returns the address of the wallet of the person who started the transaction ( who sent eth to contract A) rather than the address of contract A.

Basically, what i am asking is, if any contract in the ethereum network tries to interact with contract B, how do i find out it's address? I mean, i need to know the address of who is calling contract B in order to refuse it if it is not coming from A.

I read a little bit about internal transactions and i did not find any encouraging topics :(, so here i am looking for help.

Grateful to any reasonable suggestion!

Comment: How are you testing? msg.sender is the caller, tx.origin is EOA that signed the transaction.

Comment: As suspected, cannot reproduce `Problem here is that the variable "msg.sender" will always return the address of the wallet of the person who started the transaction (who sent eth to contract A) rather than the address of contract A`.

Comment: @Ismael: Doesn't matter how he's testing. The problem that he's describing simply does not exist in the given code (and `tx.origin` is not a test-side element anyway, it's an onchain element, which is not present in the onchain code posted here).

Comment: @goodvibration You are correct the real problem is different and it is elsewhere so I'm asking him to provide the testing code.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for trying to help. 

In fact the code itself is a little more complicated than this simple example.The example that I posted is only for better understanding the problem.

In this example, inside the "receive" function, on the contract B, i am  doing "require(msg.sender ==addrA)"  but  as i already it does not apply to the inspection that i really need, as the variable msg.sender does not contain the address of the intermediary contract that passed the value along.

Comment: Basically, i would like to know a way that i can authenticate the "conversation" between two contracts.

Comment: @DarkWinter As said by goodvibration msg.sender **is** the caller, the problem is something else if you want help you should provide a small reproducible example. The example provided does work and it doesn't have a bug.

Comment: @Ismael, thanks again for the replies. 

You are correct, there is no bug in the code.Now, is there a way  that inside the contract B ( in the function "receive" ) I could find out the address of the contract that passed the value along to contract B? I mean the address of the contract really, not the EOA who started the transaction.

Comment: @DarkWinter As goodvibration said `msg.sender` is the caller. In the example provided if someone send ether to A in A.receive msg.sender is the EOA, then it forwards ether to B, inside B.receive msg.sender is A address. One issue that you may be facing is B's receive is subject to 2300 gas stipend, if it is complex it will fail with out of gas.

Comment: @DarkWinter
I understand correctly that you want to handle the situation when your contract A calls someone else's contract E, and it in turn calls your contract B (any account -> A -> E -> B). And you want to make sure that E was called from contract A?
However, you do not want to impose the obligation of identification on the sender of the original transaction on contract A. Is this the problem?

Comment: @MadJackal, thanks for your reply. 

Not exactly this scenare. The correct flow, is :  any account ->A ->B. And I want to ensure that only this scenario is allowed.  That is why contract B must check if the sender is contract A's address. 

My problem is, on my tests using remix, when I inspect msg.sender, inside contract B i get the EOA address rather than contracts A address. I even run tests on simpler code, without any complex functions to make sure that i am not doing and mistake, and still what i get EOA address instead of  contract A's address.

Comment: I have used the validation scheme many times in practice to check the connection between two smart contracts through the msg.sender address - it always works correctly for this case.

Comment: Well, thanks everyone for clarifying than...

I still haven't found what is wrong, but it was helpful to have you guys confirming that it is the correct way to do. 
So now i can look somewhere else, as previously suggested by @Ismael and goodvibration .